# ExapndableListView with swipe to dismiss

Tags: android, expandablelistview, swipe, dismiss

I want to create an expandable list view with Swipe to Dismiss functionality much like the Outlook app does or the IOS control where you swipe to get a delete option. I have already implemented the Expandable List View, but cannot figure out how to implement the swipe to dismiss. Most libraries I found are for RecyclerViews or ListViews.

Any leads on this ?